# Database schema to manage customers subscriptions

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm currently developing a system that allows users to select a plan and subscribe to it. For simplicity, let's assume there are 3 plans: `Silver`, `Gold` and `Platinum`. Also let's assume that the prices are `Silver` = $10, `Gold` = $20 and `Platinum` = $30. The users will be charged monthly: So if a user subscribes to the `Silver` plan today, they will pay $10 and the subscription will be valid for 1 month. After that, if they didn't cancel it, the system will "renew" the subscription for another month (charging $10 again). They can pay with credit card and/or using the balance they have in their account.

I currently have the following tables:

- `users` (id, name, email, password)
- `plans`(id, name, price, is_active)
- `subscriptions` (id, user_id, plan_id, start_date, end_date)

The `plans` table stores all the active plans (`Silver`, `Gold`, `Platinum`). The `subscriptions` table stores the plan the user has subscribed. Currently I'm setting the `start_date` = the date the payment was made and `end_date` = NULL (meaning that the subscription didn't end yet).

So if the user with ID = 1 subscribes to the `Silver` plan (with ID 1) today, the `subscriptions` table will have a new record:

`(1, 1, 1, 2023-03-08, NULL)`

If he changes his mind and decides to upgrade to the `Gold` plan (with ID = 2) after 1 month, the `subscriptions` table will look like this:

`(1, 1, 1, 2023-03-08, 2023-04-08)`

`(1, 1, 2, 2023-04-08, NULL)`

Then, if he decides to cancel the subscription after 1 month, the `subscriptions` table will look like this:

`(1, 1, 1, 2023-03-08, 2023-04-08)`

`(2, 1, 2, 2023-04-08, 2023-05-08)`

The problem is when they upgrade in the middle of their current subscription:

If user with ID 2 subscribed to the `Silver` plan in January 1st the `subscriptions` table will look like this:

`(3, 2, 1, 2023-01-01, NULL)`

Since the user didn't cancel the subscription, the system processed payments for

- $10: 2023-01-01 to 2023-01-31
- $10: 2023-02-01 to 2023-02-28
- $10: 2023-03-01 to 2023-03-31

If he decides to upgrade today to the `Gold` plan, the system cannot charge him $20, because he already paid $10 for the `Silver` plan which didn't finish yet, so I need to know when the current billing cycle started (which currently I don't know, because the DB stores only the start of the first billing cycle) so I can deduct it from the $20. (He paid $10 for the whole month, but only 8 days passed so he still has 23 days (around $7 that didn't spend, so instead of charging him $20, I should charge him $13 now).

I'm thinking of adding a new record in the `subscriptions` table every time the subscription is renewed. However it kind of makes no sense, because the subscription didn't actually end, it was just renewed and also it will add tons of records to the table (maybe making it harder to query later?)

- `(3, 2, 1, 2023-01-01, 2023-01-31)`
- `(4, 2, 1, 2023-03-01, 2023-02-28)`
- `(5, 2, 1, 2023-03-01, 2023-03-08)`
- `(6, 2, 2, 2023-03-08, NULL)`

How can I model this so I can now exactly at what point of the current billing cycle they are?

Thanks in advance